# Getting highest score from mySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a database set up:
[image]

and the resulting table:

[image]

I am trying to retrieve data from the database so that the output displays the players according to who has the highest score in descending order. However, I get the following output:

[image]

Pollywinkle Anderson has a high score of 600 recorded in the database yet only her score of 200 is shown. How can I retrieve each players highest score? The score is stored as VARCHAR and I read in solutions to similar questions that it needs to be converted to an INT. I have tried to do that but it's still not working. I am very new to programming in general, any help would be appreciated. My code is below. Thank you.

```
     <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * , COUNT(*) AS `phone` FROM `players` GROUP BY 
CONCAT(`fname`, `surname`) ORDER BY MAX(CONVERT(`score`,INT)) DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Surname</th><th>Email</th><th>Score</th> 
 <th>Number of Submissions</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $fname = $row['fname'];
        $surname = $row['surname'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $score = $row['score'];
        $phone = $row['phone'];
        echo "<tr><td style='width: 200px;'>".$fname."</td><td style='width: 
200px;'>".$surname."</td><td style='width: 200px;'>".$email."</td><td 
style='width: 200px;'>".$score."</td><td style='width: 200px;'>".$phone."
```

";
        }

```
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: alter the table and make the score as `Integer` why it is `varchar`?

Comment: I tried to change VARCHAR to INT but it was giving me a "truncated incorrect INTEGER value" error so I thought maybe I shouldn't. As you can see I really am a bit clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below:

```
SELECT fname,surname,MAX(CONVERT(`score`,INT)) as score, COUNT(*) AS `submission` 
FROM `players` 
GROUP BY fname,surname
ORDER BY score desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list your players ordered by their score you don't need a count or to group by anything. All you need to do is a simple select query with an order by, like:

```
select * from players order by score
```

Comment: Hi crellee, I do still need the count because the table also needs to show how many times each player has submitted a score (Number of Submissions column)

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I misunderstood your question. If you need their number of submission, yeah you need to do a count. Also, if you need the sum of the scores you can use the SUM() function. Remember to group by both email and score